# Mongoose remove duplicate social security customer

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have `customers` who have duplicate `SocialSecurity` and I want to remove them and keep the newest customer. I am doing this by comparing `_id` and keeping the one with the largest value. Unfortunately, when I am playing with dumby data, it seems like my code does not always delete the one with the smallest `_id`. Any idea why? I thought the `$sort` would work

```
let hc = db.getSiblingDB('customer');
hc.customers.aggregate([
  {
      "$group": {
          _id: {socialsecurity: "$socialsecurity"},
          imeis: { $addToSet: "$_id" },
          count: { $sum : 1 }
      }
  },
  {
      "$match": {
          count: { "$gt": 1 }
      }
  },
  {
  $sort: {_id: 1}
  }

 ]).forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.socialsecurity.shift();
    hc.customers.remove({
        _id: {$in: doc.socialsecurity}
    });
 })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

`{ $sort: { _id: 1} }` is sorting in ascending order

So smallest will be the 1st `_id` in the array

`doc.socialsecurity.shift();` will remove 1st element from the array that is smallest one.

**Solution**

1. `{ $sort: { _id: -1 } }` sort in descending order

---

OR

2. change `doc.socialsecurity.shift();` to `doc.socialsecurity.pop();` remove the last element from the array.